# Padding in responsive email design

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to my query and especially as this is all a new field to me, finding it a little tricky but i'm almost there :)

I am basically trying to add a padding style to the social icons at the top of th email so that when the browser is resized, (essentially looked at on a smartphone) there is sufficient space between each icon.

When the screen is at full size it has equal spacing more so because the columns it sits in are loosely defined. It would be great to not have to cheat and use one image but rather the spacing kicks into effect as the screen decreases past breakpoints.

Code is below:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ZURBemails</title>
<link href="stylesheets/email2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ------------------------------------- 
        GLOBAL 
------------------------------------- */
* { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
* { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
}
.collapse {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
    width: 100%!important; 
    height: 100%;
}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        ELEMENTS 
------------------------------------- */
a { color: #2BA6CB;}

.btn {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #666;
    padding:10px 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.callout {
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#ECF8FF;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.callout a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #2BA6CB;
}

p.subtext {
    padding:0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.subtext a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #2BA6CB;
}

table.social {
/*  padding:15px; */
    background-color: #ebebeb;

}
.social .soc-btn {
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
a.fb { background-color: #3B5998!important; }
a.tw { background-color: #1daced!important; }
a.gp { background-color: #DB4A39!important; }
a.ms { background-color: #000!important; }

.body-wrap tr .container .content .nav {
    text-align: center; 
    color:#696969;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    line-height:1.5;
}
.body-wrap tr .container .content .nav a {
    text-decoration:none;   
    color:#696969;
}


.sidebar .soc-btn { 
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

p.topNote { border-top: 4px solid #1b3281; margin-top:-2px;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        HEADER 
------------------------------------- */
table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

.header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
.header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        BODY 
------------------------------------- */
table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        FOOTER 
------------------------------------- */
table.footer-wrap { width: 100%;    clear:both!important;
}
.footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
.footer-wrap .container td.content p {
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: bold;

}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        TYPOGRAPHY 
------------------------------------- */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
}
h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small { font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; }

h1 { font-weight:bold; font-size: 27px; color:#1b3180;}
h2 { font-weight:bold; font-size: 22px; color:#1b3180;}
h3 { font-weight:900; font-size: 22px; color:#0166b1;}
h4 { font-weight:500; font-size: 20px; color:#0166b1;}
h5 { font-weight:900; font-size: 17px;}
h6 { font-weight:900; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#444;}

.collapse { margin:0!important;}

p, ul { 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-size:14px; 
    line-height:1.6;
}
p.lead { font-size:17px; }
p.last { margin-bottom:0px;}

ul li {
    margin-left:5px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

/* ------------------------------------- 
        SIDEBAR 
------------------------------------- */
ul.sidebar {
    background:#ebebeb;
    display:block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.sidebar li { display: block; margin:0;}
ul.sidebar li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #666;
    padding:10px 16px;
/*  font-weight:bold; */
    margin-right:10px;
/*  text-align:center; */
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
}
ul.sidebar li a.last { border-bottom-width:0px;}
ul.sidebar li a h1,ul.sidebar li a h2,ul.sidebar li a h3,ul.sidebar li a h4,ul.sidebar li a h5,ul.sidebar li a h6,ul.sidebar li a p { margin-bottom:0!important;}



/* --------------------------------------------------- 
        RESPONSIVENESS
        Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. 
------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
.container {
    display:block!important;
    max-width:640px!important;
    margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
    clear:both!important;
}

/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
.content {
    padding:15px;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block; 
}

/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
.content table { width: 100%; }


/* Odds and ends */
.column {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}
.column tr td { padding: 15px; }
.column-wrap { 
    padding:0!important; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:600px!important;
}
.column table { width:100%;}
.social .column {
    width: 280px;
    min-width: 279px;
    float:left;
}

/* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
.clear { display: block; clear: both; }

.double .column {
    width: 280px;
    min-width: 279px;
    float:left;
}

.socialicons { padding-left:3px; }


/* ------------------------------------------- 
        PHONE
        For clients that support media queries.
        Nothing fancy. 
-------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }

    /* flex the hero image */
.container img {  width:100% !important; }


}




</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ececec">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="header container">

                <div class="content">
                  <table bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="42" style=" padding-right:10px;">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x26"></td>
                        <td rowspan="4" align="right"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/atol.jpg"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="color: #CCCCCC;"><img src="http://placehold.it/265x20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="color: #CCCCCC;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="color: #CCCCCC;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                            <td width="31%">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="30%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
                              <tr>
                      <td style="color: #CCCCCC;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                            </table></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="socialicons">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="51%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="13%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="8%"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/FB.png" alt="Facebook icon" width="24" height="23" border="0" class="socialicons"/></td>
                        <td width="7%"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/twit.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td width="7%"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/youtube.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td width="8%"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/flickr.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td width="6%"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/gplus.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>




  </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /HEADER -->


<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <div class="content">
                 <table class="nav" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/austria-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank">Austria</a>&nbsp; &#124; 
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/france-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank" >France</a>&nbsp; &#124;
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/italy-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank" > Italy</a>&nbsp; &#124; 
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/switzerland-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank" >Switzerland</a>&nbsp; &#124;
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/canada-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank" > Canada</a>&nbsp; &#124;
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/usa-ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank" > USA</a>&nbsp; &#124; 
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk/ski-resorts/ski-holidays/?em=cs080213" target="_blank"> All Ski destinations</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->
                        <p><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/hero_image_template.jpg" />  

                       </p><!-- /hero -->
                      <p class="topNote"></p>
                      <!-- Callout Panel -->
                      <h1>Welcome Mr Smith,</h1>
                        <p class="callout">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                    </p>
                        <br />
                  <h3>Subheader 1</h3>

                        <p class="subtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>
                       <table class="double" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <!--- column 1 -->
                                  <table align="center" class="column">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                
                                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/280x150" /></p>                                        
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                  </table><!-- /column 1 -->    

                                    <!--- column 2 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column" bgcolor="">
                                        <!--<tr bgcolor="#1b3281">
                                            <td>                                
                                                <p style="color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">Delta Whistler Village, CANADA</p>
                                            </td>
                                      </tr>-->
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                                          <h4>Delta Whistler Village</h4>

                                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in </p></td>
                                      </tr>                
                                  </table>                                <!-- /column 2 -->

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> <br />
                         <table class="double" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <!--- column 1 -->
                                  <table align="center" class="column">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                
                                    <p><img src="http://placehold.it/280x150" /></p>                                        
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                  </table><!-- /column 1 -->    

                                    <!--- column 2 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column" bgcolor="">
                                        <!--<tr bgcolor="#1b3281">
                                            <td>                                
                                                <p style="color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">Delta Whistler Village, CANADA</p>
                                            </td>
                                      </tr>-->
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>
                                                          <h4>Delta Whistler Village</h4>

                                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in </p></td>
                                      </tr>                
                                  </table>                                <!-- /column 2 -->

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 

                        <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->
                        <p>&nbsp;</p><!-- /hero -->

                    <!-- Callout Panel -->
                        <p class="callout">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. <a href="#">Do it Now! &raquo;</a>
                        </p><!-- /Callout Panel -->

                        <h3>Title Ipsum <small>This is a note.</small></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <a class="btn">Click Me!</a>

                        <br/>
                        <br/>                           

                        <!-- social & contact -->
                        <table class="social" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <!--- column 1 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                

                                                <h5 class="">Connect with Us:</h5>
                                                <p class=""><a href="#" class="soc-btn fb">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn tw">Twitter</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn gp">Google+</a></p>


                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><!-- /column 1 -->  

                                    <!--- column 2 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                

                                                <h5 class="">Contact Info:</h5>                                             
                                                <p>Phone: <strong>408.341.0600</strong><br/>
                Email: <strong><a href="emailto:hseldon@trantor.com">hseldon@trantor.com</a></strong></p>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><!-- /column 2 -->

                                    <span class="clear"></span> 

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table><!-- /social & contact -->


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /BODY -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<table class="footer-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container">

                <!-- content -->
                <div class="content">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">Terms</a> |
                            <a href="#">Privacy</a> |
                            <a href="#"><unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe></a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                </div><!-- /content -->

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

I am open to differing suggestions also.

Thank you.

Comment: insted of table, use div for better design. :)

Comment: Its for a responsive HTML email so it has to use tables.

Comment: ohh, i forgot. Its for email.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting into your media query something like this

```
.socialicons { padding-left: 14%; }
```

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work. It needs to work as a media query of some sort when the screen is decreased because all that happens currently is that they all get squashed together. I'd like to preserve a 5 pixel space between them as the size changes.

Comment: Gray, can you post to jsfiddle.net and example of your code? That will help me and others.

Comment: Hi MGDTech, I can but considering its an email, it cannot contain any programming languages apart from straight up HTML and CSS. I'm not sure how posting it there will help? Please clarify! :)

Comment: Using `padding` in HTML emails is not recommended anyway as that property is not supported in some email clients.

Answer (score 0):

Question: do you need 5px of space always?

One method would be to add empty td's between the items and set the width to 5 pixels, however, the same could be almost achieved by adding non-width declared cells with default font settings applied or should I say "implied" because outlook with fall back to whatever the user has set for font size display when it isn't declared (not part of the cascade for some reason...) 
Being "empty" and without width makes them a width of "auto" which means they have responsive type tendencies without being forced into a set width. See the example below:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="socialicons">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="51%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="8%" style="font-size:3px; line-height:3px;"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/FB.png" alt="Facebook icon" width="24" height="23" border="0" class="socialicons"/></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="7%" style="font-size:3px; line-height:3px;"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/twit.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="7%" style="font-size:3px; line-height:3px;"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/youtube.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="8%" style="font-size:3px; line-height:3px;"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/flickr.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="6%" style="font-size:3px; line-height:3px;"><img src="http://www.google.co.uk/emails/Template2013/images/gplus.png" border="0" width="24" height="23" alt="Facebook icon" /></td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
```

Side note: when mixing percentages and fixed width, it is probably a good practice to have one cell with no width declared to act as the "auto" size to compensate for extremely small or extremely large width views.

Of course, this is assuming any declarations in the css of the `<head>` is being stripped out by certain email clients and you need a fallback layout fix.

Add on:

```
<td width="8%" style="min-width:20px (or whatever your pixel width for the icon is); ... width:20px\9;"><img>
```

the backslash+9 hacks for IE inline forcing the width to 20 pixels.

Comment: Hi artcase, This squeezed the icons terribly, especially when using the percentages. Would you do it this way or use one image encompassing all of the icons?

Comment: added min-width declaration for browsers outside of IE, then an IE only inline hack. If your icons don't get larger (max-width:100%;) and the boxes surrounding them flex a bit, I think you'll be okay. However, if you really need the icons to stay in the same size and same spacing, make those cells and the spacers as fixed width and then make the other cells flexible percentages and one with no width declared.

Comment: thanks for getting back. so do I ADD the recent code to the code you provided yesterday or is it replacing the last td?

Comment: Add a min-width to the style declaration and make the width non-declared for the cell that contains the image. This should force the cell to be the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cellpadding="5"`.  That will preserve 5px between all your table cells.

Answer (score 0):

give the padding as 0 and in between the images in the body, use something like image spacer defining the width you want in between the icons.Spacer is blank image, that has nothing in it. This will eliminate the css and make it more consistent with all email clients.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="10" style="display:block"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is

```
<table width="680" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ebebeb">
<tr>
    <td width="100%">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size: 12px; color: #a2a2a2; font-weight: normal; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 26px; vertical-align: top; text-align:center; padding:20px 0 15px">
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.example.com">
                                                <img src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/emails/stamplia1/facebook.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.example.com">
                                                <img src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/emails/stamplia1/twitter.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.example.com">
                                                <img src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/emails/stamplia1/google.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Google" title="Google" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.example.com">
                                                <img src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/emails/stamplia1/rss.png" width="35" height="35" alt="RSS" title="RSS" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.example.com">
                                                <img src="https://www.emailonacid.com/images/emails/stamplia1/mail.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Mail" title="Mail" border="0" />
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is a jsfiddle, to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ahykdum5/